# How to load an image file from a different project in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, project, monodevelop

I have a main project. Then i want to have another project where i have only the images.
This is because i have a tool that builds for me this project.

So the main project has the lohic, and the Data Project has the images.

Well, i can load images with `UIImage.FromFile`. But only is this images ARE in the main project.

When i take a look to the app generated, i can see that , even if i change the file properties to Content, and Copy always, no image files appear at all. It seems that they are embedded as a resource.

This is not what i want at all. I want to copy a bunch of files to the iPhone, and the load it using `UIImage.FromFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, in your *image* project set all your data as **resources**. They will be embedded into the assembly produced.

Next, from your main project, use `UIImage.FromResource` to create your images. Specify the assembly (that your image project creates) and the name of the image file.

Comment: Ummm. I'm trying to port a Windows Phone App and i have no problems with it. i'm afraid that working with resources could be a bit slow, because i'm loading an image every 1/12th of second... 
But thanks, i will try!!!

Comment: You should fill an enhancement bug report (on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com for MonoDevelop, iPhone Addin) so this might be added in future releases. In the mean time, if it's not fast enough consider caching them (in memory) or extract them first (or whenever absent as iOS can remove cached items) on the `cache` directory of the application (and load them from there).